# Prove that $D_{12}$ is not cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, dihedral-groups

So I am trying to prove that $D_{12}$ and $S_4$ are not isomorphic by giving three properties that all isomorphisms to $D_{12}$ has that $S_4$ does not.

I have already proved that there is an element of order $12$ in $D_{12}$ and now I'm trying to prove that $D_{12}$ is not cyclic because I know $S_4$ is.

I know that there are at least two ways to do this: to find an element that does not divide the order of the group (there is a theorem stating that in a finite cyclic group the order of an element divides the order of the group) or to show that there is a subgroup of $D_{12}$ that is not cyclic (theorem stating every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic).

I can't find an element that does not divide the order $24$ and I'm honestly really confused on subgroups of Dihedral group.

Please help

Comment: You wrote many wrong things. $S_4$ is definitely not cyclic, because it is not even abelian. The order of an element of a finite group always divides the order of the group, doesn't matter if the group is cyclic or not.

Comment: okay now I'm really confused. Then what other properties can I prove to show that they are not isomorphic. I was planning on finding how many elements of order 4 there are in each group, because if the number is different then I can use that to prove they are not isomorphic. Unless I'm wrong, I'm pretty sure neither group is abelian so I cant use that. They also both have order 24 so I can't use that.

Comment: So should we be answering the problem in the title ($D_{12}$ is not cyclic) or the implied question in the body ($D_{12}$ is not isomorphic to $S_4$)?

Comment: Hi I'm trying to prove that they are not isomorphic but I thought S4 was cyclic but I guess I was wrong

Comment: Please don't change the question.

Comment: @Allie Better is to prove that $S_4$ has no elements of order $12$. In fact, it has no elements of order greater than $4$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I have already done that but I have to show that there are two other properties that they do not have in common

Comment: @Shaun should I just ask another question then

Comment: Yes, @Allie; that's the etiquette here.

Comment: okay @Shaun , sorry I didn't realize that

Comment: It's alright - no harm done. Please don't forget to accept an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma:** Each cyclic group is abelian.

*Proof:* Let $x,y\in G$ for a cyclic group $G$. Then $x=g^a, y=g^b$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb Z$, where $g$ is the generator of $G$. Now $xy=g^ag^b=g^{a+b}=g^{b+a}=g^bg^a=yx$.$\square$

Neither $D_{12}$ nor $S_4$ is abelian, so neither is cyclic.

Indeed, let $r$ be a nontrivial rotation in $D_{12}$ and $s$ be a flip. Then $srs=r^{-1}$, *i.e.*, $sr=r^{-1}s$ but $r\neq r^{-1}$. Also,

$$\begin{align}
(12)(13)&=(132)\\
&\neq (123)\\
&=(13)(12)
\end{align}$$

in $S_4$.

Comment: It could be useful to show why $D_{12}$ is not abelian since it's simpler but less obvious than the lemma to me

Comment: Is that better, @jacopoburelli?

Comment: Yes, I think the answer is complete now, thanks Shaun